# Android: Notifications are sent whenever phone reboots

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to display a notification every three hours from 10am to 22pm, but my application also displaying a notification whenever users open their phone. In order to solve this every time the notification process is triggered I set the current time plus 3 hours in my Shared Preference. I use this time value to trigger my repeating Alarm but it does not seems to work correctly.

How can I display notification only at the scheduled time of the repeating alarm(every three hours) and stop sending notification whenever someone reboot its phone?

My code is the following:

A Broadcast Receiver which is trggered wheneven users reboot their phone is calling the following AlarmService :

```
public class AlarmService extends Service {


    private static final String TAG = "MyService";

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {

        Calendar calendar  ;

            int sp= SharedPrefs.getDefaults("TIME", this);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, NotificationBarAlarm.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i,                   PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

     calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

     calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, sp);
     calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00); 
     calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);


         AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),3*60*60*1000 , pi);

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("TAG", "onDestroy");
    }

}
```

which is sending an Intent to the following Broadcast Receiver:

```
public class NotificationBarAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    NotificationManager notifyManager;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.d("NotificationAlarm", "onReceive");


        Time time = new Time();
        long currenttimeMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
        time.set(currenttimeMilliseconds);
        int t = time.hour;


        long updatedTime= currenttimeMilliseconds + 10800000;

        Time nextalarmmill = new Time();
        nextalarmmill.set(updatedTime);
        int nextalarm = nextalarmmill.hour;


        SharedPrefs.setDefaults("TIME", nextalarm, context);


        Log.d("UPDATE TIME", "The next alarm is set at"+" "+ nextalarm);


        notifyManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (t >= 10 && t <= 22) {

            // This Activity will be started when the user clicks the notification
            // in the notification bar
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
                    AlarmReceiverActivity.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                    notificationIntent, 0);
            Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                    "A new notification just popped in!",
                    System.currentTimeMillis());

            // sound when the notification shows up.
            Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager
                    .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            notif.sound = alarmSound;
            notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Questionnaire",
                    "Please fill it up", contentIntent);

            notifyManager.notify(1, notif);

        }


    }

}


Here is the code of the Shared Preferences:

public class SharedPrefs {


    public static void setDefaults(String key, int value, Context context) {

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt(key, value);
        editor.commit();

    }

    public static int getDefaults(String key, Context context) {

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getInt(key, 10);

    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry if my english are not correct I am not a native speaker, my question is how can I display notification only at the scheduled time of the repeating alarm(every three hours only) and stop sending notification whenever someone reboot its phone

Comment: Is the notification sent from your server or what?

Comment: I have provide my code concerning the notification process, I am using the NotificationManager.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are asking the `Alarm` to go off immedialtely for the first time when the `Alarm` is set.

Try this
`am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis() + 3*60*60*1000, 3*60*60*1000 , pi);`

Comment: Sorry about my question but I am new in programming, the calendar.getTimeInMillis() reutrn the current time ? not the time I have set at my calendar ? by this code :      calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, sp);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00); 
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

Comment: If your read the `AlarmManager` docs, you will know that the second `parameter` tells the `AlarmManager` when to trigger the first `Alarm` and if that time has already passed then it will fire the alarm immediately. In this case, using the right `firstfire` time will solve your problem. What `Calendar` gives you back should be another qustion, you can post a separate question or look for posted questions..

Comment: Yes you are right, and what you proposed me is correct however I want to trigger the alarm immediately if the phone opens at (10,13 etc) that's why I am trying to pass when to trigger the alarm from my shared preferences. I found what was the problem I was not getting and setting correctly my Shared Preference. I replaced the code and now it is working ! Thak you very much for your time and help